# How do I enable Exception Translation in Spring-Data when running from a Test?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I am using Spring-Data and want to let `PersistenceExceptions` be translated to Springs `DataAccessExceptions`.

I activated Spring-Data with `@EnableJpaRepositories` and I can see, that the `org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0` is loaded by Spring during startup. A `PersistenceExceptionTranslator` is available, too.

As I understand the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jpa.introduction) the namespace declaration `<jpa:repositories>` activates persistence exception translation for Beans annotated with `@Repository`. Is this the case for Java Configuration (`@EnableJpaRepositories`) as well?

Does this mean, I have to annotate my Spring-Data repository interface with `@Repository` or is it optional using Spring Data as configured like mentioned above?

This is the interface:

```
@Repository
public interface DemoDao extends JpaRepository<Demo, Long> {}
```

And this is the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestDaoWithEmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration.class})
@Transactional
public class DemoTest {

    @Test(expected = DataAccessException.class)
    public void testFindByTransactionStatus() throws Exception {
        persistDemoDataWithUniqueConstraintError(); // this calls DemoDao#save()
    }
}
```

This generates:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException
```

I cannot figure out how to enable the exception translation. Any ideas?

**Edit 1:**

This is the test configuration and Spring setup:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.demo.dao")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.demo.dao")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestDaoWithEmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration {
    // DataSource (EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder), EntityManagerFactory @Bean configuration

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslator persistenceExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work as you expect it to. Any chance you add the content of the configuration?

Comment: @OliverGierke I added the configuration but left out the Bean definitions for Entitymanager and embedded DB datasource. If needed, please let me know. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Same problem here, very interested in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found persistence exception translation to be working be default, using Spring 4.1.5.RELEASE and Spring Data JPA 1.7.2.RELEASE.

Per [PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.html) javadoc:

> All of Spring's applicable resource factories (e.g.
>   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) implement the
>   PersistenceExceptionTranslator interface out of the box.

My config...

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef="emfb", ...)
@ComponentScan(...)
public class TestConfig {
    @Bean public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb() { ... }
    ...
}
```

...and a JUnit4 test like...

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestConfig.class})
public class MyTest {
    ...
    @Test public void expectFKViolation() { ... }
    ...
}
```

...results in:

```
Tests in error: expectFKViolation(...): ...; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException
```

Grepping the test output for `org.hibernate.PropertyValueException`:

```
o.s.t.c.s.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: 
context [ ..., testException = org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: 
not-null ...; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException ... ]
```

Setting the translated, testException type on the test method makes the test go green:

```
@Test(expected="org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException.class")
public void expectFKViolation() { ... }
```